# Is Entity Framework fast enough for data retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I am designing a new set of projects including a WCF service that must handle as many as 50 requests per minute.

This will be a Microsoft stack using .NET 4.0 and C#.

Each request will validate the data and if it passes, retrieve data via a stored proc on a SQL Server 2008 server.

The response should be returned within 5 seconds of the request, if possible.

Both the request and the response XML are under 3K each and are fairly simple.

I plan to set up a load-balancer to handle the requests but I need to know if EF will be fast enough to pull this off or if I need to go with something else.

Note that none of this is built yet so I have the freedom to build something from scratch.

Comment: If you're worried about performance maybe you should consider looking at your xml serializer as a bottleneck...and if you're invoking a stored procedure, just use Dapper.  You get your strongly typed object serialization and all the speed you can handle.

Comment: Yes, EF is very fast, but if it will be enough is relative, it depends on your scenario, but don't worry, EF performs great.
Just for reference, I have an application that performs more than 100 transactions per second with EF, but off course the database, stored procedures and queries are tuned, so I think the database is a very important issue to care about too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is relatively fast ([Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)), however, if ALL you're doing is invoking stored procedures, Dapper or some other MICRO-ORM will be much faster. If you need to do more complex O/RM tasks, like LINQ queries against the database, [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) is generally faster than EF6, but EF6 supports more concepts, such as code-first that LINQ to SQL was never meant to do.

I don't think your O/RM will be your bottleneck, no matter what way you go about it: more likely the stored procedure (or no indexes, if you go the O/RM query route and don't figure out what indexes you need beforehand) will be your performance bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. And thanks to David and Ricardo who commented on my question too.